# How to assign a value from expression to data attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In below sample piece of code, how do i assign data returned from expression `{{(results | filter: myFilter)}}` to **data** attribute instead of `results`.

```
 <img ng-json-export-excel data="results" src=../dl.png/>
```

Below are my trials that didn't work.

```
data="{{(results | filter: myFilter)}}"
data="results | filter: myFilter"
```

Please advice.

Thanks,
Reddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the filter work in js as follows.

`$scope.filteredResults = filter1Filter(results, myFilter);`

Now in HTML you can do like this:

`<img ng-json-export-excel data="{{filteredResults}}" src=../dl.png/>`

This might help you. All the best.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the solution that hit me but I would like to take advantage of expressions and do it on html page itself. It is possible?

Comment: Doing it in HTML page greatly reduces performance. Better to do it in js.

Comment: Read this article. This may help you [link](https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/)

Comment: Above link was helpful (Y). Thank you

Comment: Thank you. All the best.